# Calling common methods without a common interface

Tags: java, reflection

I have some generated code (i.e. it cannot be changed) that looks something like this.

```
class Generated1 {
    public String getA() {
        return "1";
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
    }

    public void setD(String d) {
    }
}

class Generated2 {
    public String getA() {
        return "2";
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
    }

    public void setD(String d) {
    }
}
```

I am exploring these objects by reflection. None of them implement any common interface but there's many of them and I want to treat them as if they implement:

```
interface CommonInterface {
    String getA();

    void setB(String b);

    void setC(String c);

    void setD(String d);
}
```

It certainly should be possible. This is considered perfectly good code

```
class CommonInterface1 extends Generated1 implements CommonInterface {
    // These are perfectly good classes.
}

class CommonInterface2 extends Generated2 implements CommonInterface {
    // These are perfectly good classes.
}
```

I suppose what I'm looking for is something like:

```
private void doCommon(CommonInterface c) {
    String a = c.getA();
    c.setB(a);
    c.setC(a);
    c.setD(a);
}

private void test() {
    // Simulate getting by reflection.
    List<Object> objects = Arrays.asList(new Generated1(), new Generated2());
    for (Object object : objects) {
        // What is the simplest way to call `doCommon` with object here?
        doCommon(object);
    }
}
```

My question: How do I treat an object that doesn't `implement` an `interface` but actually has all the code to do so as if it *does* implement the interface.

I want to replace

```
private void doCommon(Generated1 c) {
    String a = c.getA();
    c.setB(a);
    c.setC(a);
    c.setD(a);
}

private void doCommon(Generated2 c) {
    String a = c.getA();
    c.setB(a);
    c.setC(a);
    c.setD(a);
}

...
```

with

```
private void doCommon(CommonInterface c) {
    String a = c.getA();
    c.setB(a);
    c.setC(a);
    c.setD(a);
}
```

I know I can use a `Proxy` like this but I'd really prefer to use something better.

```
private void test() {
    // Simulate getting by reflection.
    List<Object> objects = Arrays.asList(new Generated1(), new Generated2());
    for (Object object : objects) {
        // What is the simplest way to call `doCommon` with object here?
        doCommon(adapt(object));
    }
}

private CommonInterface adapt(Object o) {
    return adapt(o, CommonInterface.class);
}

public static <T> T adapt(final Object adaptee,
                          final Class<T>... interfaceToImplement) {
    return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        adaptee.getClass().getClassLoader(),
        interfaceToImplement,
        // Call the equivalent method from the adaptee.
        (proxy, method, args) -> adaptee.getClass()
            .getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes())
            .invoke(adaptee, args));
}
```

Comment: instantiate the implementations of the interfaces.  have a List<CommonInterface> instead of List<Object>

Comment: `class CommonInterface1 extends Generated1 implements CommonInterface` means that all `CommonInterface1` objects are also `Generated1` objects, but the other way around is not true. If you `new` a `Generated1` object, it isn't a `CommonInterface1` object.

Comment: If you're exploring them by reflection, you don't need an interface. Just look for a specific named method by reflection. If it's present, call it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat - added a simple question.

Comment: How many of those GeneratedX classes do you have? Because if you only have a few, you can just write a few adapter classes that implement the common interface and delegate to the adaptee object. And use instanceof to know which Adapter to create. Even if you have many, since you're using code generation anyway, you could generate the Adapter classes too.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using reflection, you don't need the two `CommonInterfaceX` classes, you can use a proxy implementing `CommonInterface`:

```
public class Wrapper implements InvocationHandler {
    private final Object delegate;

    public static <T> T wrap(Object obj, Class<T> intf) {
        ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(cl, new Class<?>[] {intf},
                        new Wrapper(obj));
        return intf.cast(proxy);
    }

    private Wrapper(Object delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
            throws Throwable {
        Method dmethod = delegate.getClass().getMethod(
                method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
        return dmethod.invoke(delegate, args);
    }
}
```

You can use this class as follows:

```
List<Object> objects = Arrays.asList(new Generated1(), new Generated2());
for (Object object : objects) {
    CommonInterface proxy = Wrapper.wrap(object, CommonInterface.class);
    doCommon(proxy);
}
```

UPDATE: note that the same `Wrapper` class works with any interface.

Comment: Using a `Proxy` is certainly an option but I would like to avoid it if possible. Also see the end of my question (added after you posted this answer) a much simpler mechanism for creating the proxy. They are very powerful but still worth avoiding if there is another option.

Comment: Because it's just more reflection which shouldn't be needed. Witness my `// These are perfectly good classes.`

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to achieve a static type relationship between `Generated1` and `Generated2`.

Even if you created `CommonInterface1` and `CommonInterface2`, you still wouldn't be able to statically use a `Generated1` object as a `CommonInterface1` because `new Generated1()` ***is not*** a `CommonInterface1` (and will never become one)

By far the simplest solution is to change your code generation to add the `CommonInterface` to `Generated1` and `Generated2`.

If that's absolutely impossible, the only other way to avoid this code duplication is to go for reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manuallly by reflection.

```
public class Generated {
    public String getA() {
        return "A";
    }

    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "hello " + name;
    }
}

public class Helper {
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getA";
    private static final String METHOD_WITH_PARAM_NAME = "sayHello";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Generated generated = new Generated();

        accessMethod(generated);
        accessMethodWithParameter(generated);
    }

    private static void accessMethod(Generated g) throws Exception {
        Method[] methods = g.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        for(Method method : methods) {
            if(isCommonMethod(method)) {
                String result = (String) method.invoke(g);
                System.out.println(METHOD_NAME + "() = " + result);
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isCommonMethod(Method m) {
        return m.getName().equals(METHOD_NAME) && m.getReturnType().equals(String.class);
    }

    private static void accessMethodWithParameter(Generated g) throws Exception {
        Method[] methods = g.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        for(Method method : methods) {
            if(isCommonMethodWithParameter(method)) {
                String result = (String) method.invoke(g, "Max");
                System.out.println(METHOD_WITH_PARAM_NAME + "(\"Max\") = " + result);
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isCommonMethodWithParameter(Method m) {
        return m.getName().equals(METHOD_WITH_PARAM_NAME) &&
                m.getReturnType().equals(String.class) &&
                m.getParameterTypes().length == 1 &&
                m.getParameterTypes()[0].equals(String.class);
    }

}
```

Output is

```
getA() = A
sayHello("Max") = hello Max
```

Comment: But to be honest I like the answer of @MauricePerry more. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to replace as your comment. I think you can do it easily

First, you create interface `CommonInterface`

```
interface CommonInterface {
    String getA();

    void setB(String b);

    void setC(String c);

    void setD(String d);
}
```

After that, you create 2 class `Generated1` and `Generated2` inherited `CommonInterface`

```
class Generated1 implements CommonInterface {
    @overide
    public String getA() {
        return "1";
    }

    @overide
    public void setB(String b) {
    }

    @overide
    public void setC(String c) {
    }

    @overide
    public void setD(String d) {
    }
}

class Generated2 implements CommonInterface {

    @overide
    public String getA() {
        return "2";
    }

    @overide
    public void setB(String b) {
    }

    @overide
    public void setC(String c) {
    }

    @overide
    public void setD(String d) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly the `Generated...` classes cannot be changed. (Not the downvoter).